# How to create active object 'IN' condition query

Tags: java, conditional-statements, hsqldb, active-objects

my current query is as below and it works fine for single user:

```
1
ao.find(da.class, Query.select().where("user=?",user)
```

Now, i want to change this query to fetch multi users data as below , but it did not work and giving me invalid column name.

```
1
ao.find(da.class, Query.select().where("user IN (?)",user)
```

Also, tried by applying single qutoes. Even single user come in param value then also not worked and giving same error.

can any one suggest me whats wrong and have to correct here?

Error as ,

```
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column not found: user in statement [SELECT * FROM       PUBLIC.AO_0371A8_da WHERE "user" IN (?)]
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prep
```

OR when - where("used "('?')" and verified for single user

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column not found: user in statement [SELECT * FROM      PUBLIC.AO_0371A8_da WHERE "user" IN ('?')]
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareState
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use IN queries, you need to construct the placeholder list yourself. Here is a snippet taken from: https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/AO-263?focusedCommentId=69495&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-69495

```
MyEntity[] findEntities(Iterable<String> matchValues) {
    String placeholderCommaList = Joiner.on(", ").join(Iterables.transform(matchValues, Functions.constant("?")));
    Object[] matchValuesArray = Iterables.toArray(matchValues, Object.class);
    return ao.find(MyEntity.class, "primary_key_field_name", Query.select().where("match_field_name IN (" + placeholderCommaList + ")", matchValuesArray));
}
```

It's important, that the number of placeholders ("?") matches the number of arguments.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but seriously, wtf.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

You cannot retrieve multiple rows from the database with one parameter in the IN clause. This query is equivalent to the first query. For two users you need IN(?,?), for three users you need IN(?,?,?).

The second query gives errors probably because the column name is USER. Try a different name for your variable and database column.

Always report the error when you ask for a solution to a problem.

You may be able to quote the user field name if you cannot change it. But I don't know if the ORM changes the where string or not.

```
ao.find(da.class, Query.select().where("\"USER\" IN (?)",user)
```

Comment: Is there way to make it work without changing "user" field, it's working fine for single user using first query. But not work while using for multi user through-       where"(user IN (?)",userparam), userparam has multiple value - "user1,user2,user3"